# How can I maintain an accurate count of sub-records in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (Member and Visit) in a SQL Server databse

```
Member [PK MemberId, MemberName, ...] ~3 million records   
Visit [PK VisitId, FK MemberId, ...] ~ 75 million records
```

I have a view that returns the member and how many visits they've had which is something like this:

```
SELECT M.MemberId, M.MemberName, COUNT(*)  
FROM Visit V   
LEFT JOIN Member M on V.MemberId = V.MemberId  
GROUP BY M.MemberId, M.MemberName
```

Which is extremely slow (over 1 hour) even though the Visit.MemberID is indexed because COUNT() will do either a table scan or an index scan.

So I'd like to maintain a VisitCount on the Member table and I'm wondering if there is an industry standard way to ensure that this number is correct.

Should I use a trigger on the Visit table in increment and decrement the Member.VisitCount? Or is there a better way to do this with SQL Server?

Comment: Weird: I've tried 20x to format the SQL statement but SO can't save it when I to.

Comment: You might require to go to trigger but it is completely overkill for your scenario... What is index on Visit? Why it goes to table scan? Which column has clustered index on that table?

Comment: The IX_MemberId index on the Visit table is non-unique and non-clustered and just on the MemberId...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views):
Use count_big(*) instead of count(*) and use inner join instead of left to respect indexed view limitations;
This view will be maintaned by server, all you need to get your final result is to add outer rows

Comment: Thanks - this really did solve the problem beautifully - query now runs in less than 1% of the previous time